# How to get callback to work with "this" in class scope

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a question about following code to print out "this.text".

I need to have a wrapper function to make it work. This is too troublesome.

Is there a simpler way (without additional wrapper) to get it work?

```
  function Class1() {
    this.text = "test";
  }

  Class1.prototype.show = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.text);
  }

  var testClass = new Class1();

  function funWithCallBack(cb) {
    cb();
  }

  // it will show "undefined" because "this" scope changes to window
  funWithCallBack(testClass.show); 

  function wrapper() {
    testClass.show();
  }

  // this one will work but troublesome
  funWithCallBack(wrapper)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function like this:

```
// it will show "undefined" because "this" scope changes to window
funWithCallBack(testClass.show);
```

to this:

```
// anonymous function to use the right object for the method
funWithCallBack(function() {
    testClass.show()
});
```

---

Your problem occurs because when you pass `testClass.show` as the callback, it just gets the function reference and there is no association with `testClass` any more.  But, you can create a temporary function that binds them together using  [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), but it isn't supported in some older browsers which is why I generally just use the anonymous function.

The `.bind()` implementation would look like this:

```
// use .bind() to make sure the method is called in the right object context
funWithCallBack(testClass.show.bind(testClass));
```